# Aptana error: parsing data for android-22 failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, aptana3

After bringing the versions of JRE/JDK/ADT to the same (at least compatible) level, I still encounter the above mentioned error in Aptana Studio 3.

Java and JDK are 1.7.

During startup Aptana tries to rebuild and stops with this error message.

> Update:

After "Android SDK: Resolving Error Markers" Aptana status changes to "Building Workspace", "Initializing Index" and finally stops with "Problem Occurred" message:

> 'Loading data for Android 5.1.1' has encountered a problem,
>   Parsing data for andoid-22 failed.

Details:

> Parsing Data for android-22 failed
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Research brought up so far that there's an incompatibility with Java 1.8, which I deactivated. Since I am rather a semi professional programmer, I have not much knowledge of how to handle such dependencies.

Comment: Please post the entire error message (and stack trace if available)

Comment: I added the whole error message. Sorry but I do not know where to find a stack trace for the starting process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I believe it was related to quite outdated Eclipse version - I was still trying to build with Eclipse Indigo.

Now I have the following setup working for me:

- I installed Eclipse Luna Java developer version
- I installed the ADT plugin (I believe the URL changed since earlier versions): https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- I have JDK and JRE latest of 1.7 (32 bit as my entire system is 32 bit).

With this the error is gone and I am able to build with Android target level 22.

PS: By the way the error is not related to aptana at all as far as I understand.

Comment: Well, yes: I will give a second installation (plain Eclipse this time) a try. Bit disappointed abvout how hard it seems to get a configuration up and running for so many android developers. Imho moving to Android Studio shouldn't be a forced solution.

Answer (score 0):

"Answer in progress":

Uninstalling all of the Android-22 SDKs for now solved the error message thing, but I think that is just the workaround, not the final solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error in eclipse as even though a 1.8 JRE was installed and the system default, eclipse was still actually starting on a 1.6 JRE.

Check to make sure your Aptana is running on a 1.7 or 1.8 JRE

Similar to eclipse, with Aptana you edit the AptanaStudio3.ini file to set a specific JRE to use.

Add the lines:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

Where C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\ is the appropriate path to your 1.7/1.8 JRE.

Comment: mmm. i don't think this is relevant for this question.

Comment: It very much is... I was getting this very error message this morning. Added the vm argument and now it loads 5.1.1 quite happily. I think you need to try it before down voting.

Comment: Glad that it cured your issue with 5.1.1 under eclipse. I do not understand the downvoting, too. Maybe it is a sophisticated thing about the rules here far beyond my understanding. Anyways - thanks for contributing.